# iOS simulator scrolling action too fast

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, ios-simulator

After upgrading flutter 3.7.0 yesterday, my iOS Simulator's scrolling speed changed to fast. Every single scrollable speed changed significantly. I don't want to downgrade flutter version, because when I create new flutter file and start iOS Simultator, it works fine. So I think it is not a flutter version problem. How could I do?

[image]

Comment: fyi, rosetta things no works for me.